# Как в Google maps API задать стартовую позицию для карты из множества адресов?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Друзья, очень нужна помощь, всю голову сломал, есть Google карта, с массивом адресов:

```
var locations = [
['Москва, Россия', 'Москва', 'infowindow 1'],
['Барнаул, Россия', 'Барнаул', 'infowindow 2'],
['Улан-Удэ, Россия', 'Улан-Удэ', 'infowindow 3']
];
```

Далее из адресов получаем позицию на карте с помощью функции geocode и в цикле расставляем маркеры на карте, и по клику переходим перемещаемся по ним.

Но вот беда, при загрузке карты, центр карты ставится на ПОСЛЕДНИЙ элемент массива, на последний адрес, на последний маркер.  А мне нужно на первый, как это сделать ума не приложу, уже все испробовал :( помогите пожалуйста.

Вот поднял пример https://codepen.io/Cheizer/pen/ZgKPNG

Как видите адрес начальный ставится на Улан-Удэ, а нужно на Москву. Как это сделать?

Comment: Проблема похоже в том, что запускаются 3 асинхронных запроса на геокодировании, в каком порядке они отработают - чистый рандом. А нужно сначала дождаться когда они все отработают, а уже затем выставлять позицию карты. Но как это сделать, я не понимаю :(

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример моего кода, который реализовывает эту задачу.

```
    const data = [
    {id: "1", fullname: "FirstName LastName",
    address: "Canada, 1150-206, Lisbon metropolitan area, Lisbon, R. Júlio de 
    Andrade 3"
    latitude: 38.719463
    longitude: -9.1410403
},
   {
id: "2",   address: "Panama, 65806-2543, Missouri, Springfield"
    fullname: "Ivan Petrov"
    latitude: 37.2034299
    longitude: -93.2935778
   }]

data.forEach(item => {
        item.coords = new google.maps.LatLng(+item.latitude, +item.longitude);
        this.listPersons.push(item);
      });

const bounds = extendBounds(this.listPersons);
      map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setCorrectZoom(map);
      }, 200);

function extendBounds(listCoords) {
      const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      listCoords.forEach(item => {
        bounds.extend(item.coords);
      });
      return bounds;
    };

function setCorrectZoom(map) {
      const currentZoom = map.getZoom();
      if (currentZoom > 15) {
        map.setZoom(15);
      }
    };
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем понял в каком месте это использовать в моем случае, это в самой geocoding?  Или после inicialize?  И зачем там setTimeout?

Comment: После того, как получите координаты и создадите маркеры  - используйте этот код. Все методы нативные. SetTimeout можете не использовать. Ваш код не смотрел

Comment: попробовал уже, ничего не меняется и ругается на forEach : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: Можно на ваш целый код взглянуть? Есть результат его работы? По куску мне сложно понять как это встроить в мой код.

Comment: Ну так Вы же должны адаптировать этот код, под свой. В итерируемом массиве должны быть поле с координатами  и т.д.

Comment: Добавил код....

Comment: у меня нет такой проблемы с широтой и долготой, а у вас с широтой и долготой пример, у меня же маркер ставится исключительно по адресу. geocoding для того и использую что бы по адресу узнать широту и долготу, а не вписывать их руками в массив. Вы в примере совсем не используете geocode.

Answer (score 0):

Решение, в цикле добавить

```
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    //geocodeAddress(locations[i]);
  geocodeAddress(locations[i], i == 0);
}
```

И в функцию geocodeAddress добавить аргумент isSetToCenterMap, и сделать на него проверку пере установкой центра карты

```
 if (isSetToCenterMap){
       map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
   }
```

Осталось одна проблема, иногда подглючивает карта, кликаешь на один город, а показывает предыдущий или следующий, непонятно почему.